# Header sliver not floating over the list in a NestedScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Material Design screen where I use a `RefreshIndicator` for pull-to-refresh effect. However, I need the `RefreshIndicator` to appear below the `SliverAppBar`; due to that, I can't just leave the `SliverAppBar` inside the list's `CustomScrollView` and I need to give it a header place in a `NestedScrollView`.

The problem comes because I can't seem to **synchronize the general scroll of the list and the header**. The list scrolls fine, but the header does not. I want it to float and snap upon scroll up/down.

```dart
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, _) => [
          SliverOverlapAbsorber(
            handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
            sliver: SliverAppBar(
              floating: true,
              snap: true,
              title: Text('Title'),
            ),
          )
        ],
        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: () { /* do stuff */ },
            child: CustomScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController, // needed for an infinite scroll items loading effect
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverOverlapInjector(
                  handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context)
                )
                // more slivers
              ],
            ),
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I guess I am missing something regarding the injecting/absorbing of the header sliver overlap.

**How can I make the `SliverAppBar` and the general `CustomScrollView` scroll synchronously?**

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for my case:

adding `floatHeaderSlivers: true` to NestedScrollView

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17518#issuecomment-641629975